# Returning base address in C(Pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning pointers and i tried this following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
char* getword()
{
    char*temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    cin>>temp;
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
   char *a;
   a=getword();
   cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

To my level of understanding, `a` is a pointer to a character, and in the function `getword()` I returned `temp` which I think the base `&temp[0]`. I thought that the output would be the first character of the string I enter, but I got the entire string in `stdout`. How does this work?

Comment: This is not `C` code. Its `C++`.

Comment: getword() is returning address of 10 characters startsed from &temp[0].

Comment: @MukitChowdhury its not returning the address of 10 character. it's  returning the `base address` to a memory block of size of 10 characters.

Comment: hummm... your explanation is more accurate. :)

Comment: If you don't even know how the language you are using is called, it's a bit premature to jump directly to pointers.

Comment: `cout << *a;` You need to dereference `a`

Answer (score 2):

In the tradition of C, a `char*` represents a string.  Indeed, any string literal in your program (e.g. `"hello"`) will have a type of `const char *`.

Thus, `cout::operator<<( const char * )` is implemented as a string-output.  It will output characters beginning at the address it is given, until it encounters the string terminator (otherwise known as null-terminator, or `'\0'`).

If you want to output a single character, you need to dereference the pointer into a `char` type.  You can choose one of the following syntaxes:

```
cout << *a;    // Dereference the pointer
cout << a[0];  // Use array index of zero to return the value at that address
```

It should be noted that the code you provided isn't very C++ish.  For starters, we generally don't use `malloc` in C++.  You then leak the memory by not calling `free` later.  The memory is uninitialised and relies on `cin` succeeding (which might not be the case).  Also, you can only handle input strings of up to 9 characters before you will get undefined behaviour.

Perhaps you should learn about the [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) library and start using it.

Comment: _"any string literal in your program (e.g. "hello") will have a type of `const char *`."_ That's not true.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that `char*` "points to a character". But, by convention, and because with pointers there is no other way to do so, we also use it to "point to more than one character".

Since use of `char*` almost *always* means you're using a pointer to a C-style string, the C++ streams library makes this assumption for you, printing the `char` that your pointer points to … and the next … and the next … and the next until `NULL` is found. That's just the way it's been designed to work.

You can print *just* that character if you like by dereferencing the pointer to obtain an actual `char`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `std::cout` is an `ostream` and providing a char* variable as input to `operator<<` invokes a particular operator function overload to write characters to the `ostream`.

`std::ostream` also has a operator overload for writing a single character to itself.

I'm assuming you now know how to dereference a `char*` variable, but you should be using `std::string` instead of an unsafe `char*` type.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` is an overloaded operator and when it receives a `char *` as an operand then it treats it as a pointer to c style string and it will print the entire string.
If you want to print the first character of the string then use

```
cout << *a;
```

or

```
cout << a[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code

```
   

    #include  <stdio.h>
    #include  <stdlib.h>

    char* getword()
    {
        char*temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
        scanf("%s",temp);
        return temp;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char *a;
        a = getword();
        int currChar = 1;
        printf("%c",*(a + currChar));  //increment currChar to get next character
        return 0;
    }
```